# BoehmGC, wasm malloc and finalizers

Tags: webassembly, boehm-gc

I've managed to get BoehmGC working on webassembly by forcing all roots on the "side stack". This is all working fine *except* for cases where there are lots of finalizers. It all works if I don't have finalizers, no matter how many objects I allocate. As soon as I set a finalizer it fails because an object is corrupted. The finalizer seems to get called on an invalid object (the value at 0 was invalid or it was never allocated in the first place).

Now I realize it sounds a bit vague, but does this ring a bell to anyone?

```
__GC_Finalizer 
GC_notify_or_invoke_finalizers 
GC_generic_malloc 
GC_malloc
```

It alwyas fails on this callstack.

__GC_Finalizer gets called tons of times with success and does nothing more than call a vmt method. Pseudo code looks like:

```
(*(FnPtrWithThis**)obj))[8](obj)
```

It fails on this already, where obj does not point to a valid vmt (all which are constant in the data segment, but the vmt it points to isn't a real vmt address).

If anyone has some info I could look into, like docs on how the finalizers work internally, or places I could debug, really any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It is better to report bdwgc issues on the github.